# disable plaintext password in ldap

Tags: ldap, openldap

I have a openldap server v3 that is storing passwords in plain text, is there anyway by which we can change the password to be stored in SSHA format by default. I use Apache DS to login to the directory tree and i see the user passwords in plaintext which in turn is a security keyhole for my firm. Please suggest as to how i enable forced SSHA password mechanism and turn of clear text.

Let me know if anyone needs more data from my side to answer this. Many thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the parameter

```
password-hash
```

in your config to define the type of hashing (ex {SSHA}).

Comment: Thanx for the response, but through the backend side i mean using ldapsearch and slapcat i see the password in encrypted format but using ldap browsers tool i can view the password in plaintext.

Comment: @user191962 `openLDAP` will not automatically convert existing fields. The configuration setting will only apply to new password change operations. However, given that you are currently storing the passwords unencrypted, you can replace the existing fields "manually" (use a script) with SSHA equivalents.

Comment: Update:- I modified the password policy and the server is now hashing the password. One thing is still my issue is that how to change my existing plaintext password as the new change is working for the newly created users. When i use the ldapmodify i am only able to change a single-single user but not in a bulk. There are around 800+ users and doing manually will not be a solution.